# how to find general solution of the system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have

$$x' = \begin{pmatrix} 2 && 2 \\ -2 && 2\end{pmatrix}x + \begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

what steps should I take to solve it?

if this was homogenious system I'd:

1.) find eigenvalues

2.) find eigenvectors

2a.) find generalized eigenvectors (if any)

3.)  write the answer properly

but what should be done here? I have never solved these systems before, general represintation does not seem helpful to me, I need real example but was not able to find any.

Comment: See it as $z'=2(1+i)z+4$ and solve as a (complex-valued) scalar equation.